# Selenium: Unable to call click on button element

Tags: python, selenium

So I am using Python to access the URL `https://losangeles.craigslist.org/wst/sub/d/furnished-master-bedroom-with/6721294465.html` and want to click reply button. So far I have tried the following code but not working

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('https://losangeles.craigslist.org/wst/sub/d/furnished-master-bedroom-with/6721294465.html')
    sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.reply-button').click()
```

I inspected via FireFox and found this:

Is there anyway I rather call jQuery click as given in the JS file?

If things worked with FF I will eventually use PhantomJS for the purpose.

[image]

**Update**

As the user `Infern0` suggested the typo. It does click but some how does not load the pop up with the content and I see the below:

[image]

Comment: If the button loads a popup, you may need to switch windows to that popup before you try to do anything with it. This happens because the popup isn't really 'part of the webpage' so you have to switch windows in Selenium and then click things on the popup, otherwise you aren't really doing anything to the popup. However, I don't know if you're running anything after this code. Do you have a stacktrace of the error when you click the reply button and get the above image?

Comment: @Redacted that is a lightbox pop up. Not a separate window

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. When I say 'new window' I mean the command in selenium to access the popup, not like a new tab in the browser. when handling popups in selenium you need to move from the current webpage to the popup. this might help explain: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/handle-alerts-popups-selenium-webdriver-selenium-tutorial-16/ If I'm still wrong then I'd need to see a stacktrace of the error in your code. If your code isn't throwing an error it might be the website itself and I would try maybe using a different selector/locator for the reply_button.

Comment: As Infern0 suggested in his (now deleted) answer, your CSS selector is not correct. It should be `reply_button` not `reply-button`. You might try adding a wait for clickable before clicking the Reply button. From some of your other comments, it sounds like you have made updates to your code but haven't updated your question. If that's true, please update your question with the current attempts and results.

Comment: Oh... and don't post screenshots of code (including HTML). Instead paste it as text and properly format it.

Comment: @JeffC > You might try adding a wait for clickable

Do you mean to use `wait untill`?

Comment: Yes, ExpectedConditions wait until clickable.